# The right way to change a <select> value in a stateful React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, html-select

I'm rendering a `<select>` in a stateful component:

```
class StatefulContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {mode: 'all'};
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <form>
                <select value={this.state.mode} onChange={this.handleModeSelection}>
                    <option value='all'>Show all</option>
                    <option value='one'>Just the first one</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>;
    }

    handleModeSelection({target: {value}}) {
        this.setState({mode: value});
    }
}

React.render(
    <StatefulContainer/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and can't figure out why it's impossible for the browser user to change the selected option to `one`. Here's a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/xexafoyesu/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: See [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Felix is already hinting in the comments, when you use ES6 classes for React components you cannot rely on React to call callbacks (like `handleModeSelection`) in the right context (documented [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding)).

There's various ways to fix this. A common one is to bind the callback(s) in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {mode: 'all'};
  this.handleModeSelection = this.handleModeSelection.bind(this);
}
```